# How do i avoid "Subscript out of Range?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, fill

I am having an issue with the "Subscript out of Range" error message. I got some help writing a code that loops a long list of stocks. The code basically makes all of the vectors even so i can use it in a panel data setting.

The loop stops after 4 stocks and gives me a "Subscript out of Range" error.
I can run the code over the first 95 "i" i.e. if i transform the first part:

```
For i = 4 To 95
        If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then Clean_Stock_2 (i)
```

Code:

```
**Sub Outer_Loop()
For i = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row**
    If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then Clean_Stock_2 (i)
Next i
End Sub


Sub Clean_Stock_2(ByVal r As Long)

Dim Stock(31, 5)
Dim Quarter(31)
Dim Bo As Boolean

Charge = 0

'Frame
For i = 0 To 31
    Stock(i, 0) = Cells(r, 1)
    Stock(i, 1) = Cells(r, 2)
    Stock(i, 2) = Cells(r, 3)
    Stock(i, 5) = "Q" & Format(DateAdd("q", i, #1/1/2011#), "q-YYYY")
    Quarter(i) = Stock(i, 5)
Next i

'Data
Do While Cells(r, 1) = Stock(0, 0)
    Qu = "Q" & Format(Cells(r, 4), "q-YYYY")
    rr = Application.Match(Qu, Quarter, 0)
    If Not IsError(rr) Then
        Stock(rr, 3) = Cells(r, 4)
        Stock(rr, 4) = Cells(r, 5)
        If Not Bo Then Charge = Stock(rr, 4): Bo = True
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop

'fill
For i = 0 To 31
    If Stock(i, 4) = 0 Then
        Stock(i, 4) = Charge
    Else
        Charge = Stock(i, 4)
    End If
Next i
'Output
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lr = IIf(lr < 3, 3, lr)
Cells(lr, "I").Resize(32, 6) = Stock
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through with F8 and find which line in Clean_Stock_2 is producing the error.